# Equivalent of Matlab "clearvars -except" in R

Tags: r, matlab, variables

I want to remove some of the variables, NOT all as `remove()` and `rm` would do.
In Matlab I'd wright:
`clearvars -except Environnement Species *_species Latitude Longitude`

Comment: So you want to delete all variables except for specified ones?

Comment: @JanSila Excactly! Do you have something in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can do. This creates `a,b,c` and deletes everything the the `Global Env` except for `b`.

```
a<-1
b<-2
c<-1:5
rm(list = ls()[!ls() %in% c("b")])
```

Comment: `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), "b"))`

Comment: yh, beats mine, saw in the duplicate :) thanks !